# Zeros of a family of number theoretic polynomials

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, algebraic-geometry, analytic-number-theory

For $n \geq 2$, denote the primes less than or equal to $n$ by $p_1 = 2, p_2 = 3, \ldots, p_{k(n)}$, and define a polynomial $P_n \in \mathbb{C}[z_1, \ldots, z_{k(n)}]$ by
$$P_n(z_1, \ldots, z_{k(n)})
= \sum_{m = 1}^{n} m^{-1/2}
\prod_{p_j^{\ell} \parallel m} z_j^{\ell}.$$
Here $p_j^{\ell} \parallel m$ denotes that $p_j^{\ell}$ is the highest power of $p_j$ dividing $m$.

To give concrete examples for small $n$, we have:

- $P_2(z_1) = 1 + 2^{-1/2} z_1$
- $P_3(z_1, z_2) = 1 + 2^{-1/2} z_1 + 3^{-1/2} z_2$;
- $P_4(z_1, z_2) = 1 + 2^{-1/2} z_1 + 3^{-1/2} z_2 + 2^{-1} z_1^2$;
- $P_5(z_1, z_2, z_3) = 1 + 2^{-1/2} z_1 + 3^{-1/2} z_2 + 2^{-1} z_1^2 + 5^{-1/2} z_3$.

**The question:** For which $n$ does $P_n$ have a zero in the closed unit polydisc, i.e. the set
$$\{ (w_1, \ldots, w_{k(n)}) : | w_1 |, \ldots, | w_{k(n)} | \leq 1 \}?$$

---

Certainly there's no such zero for $n = 2$. For many $n \geq 3$, I can show that there's a zero by restricting the $z_j$ to real values and observing that $P_n$ is $1$ at the origin but negative either when every $z_j = -1$ or when $z_1 = 0$ and all other $z_j = -1$.

An interesting connection I've come across is that
$$P_n(-1, -1, \ldots, -1)
= \sum_{m = 1}^{n} \frac{\lambda(m)}{m^{1/2}}
= L_{1/2}(n).$$
Here $\lambda$ is the Liouville function, and $L_{1/2}$ comes from the family of weighted summatory functions
$$L_{\alpha}(x)
= \sum_{m \leq x} \frac{\lambda(m)}{m^{\alpha}}.$$

An [article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1108.1524.pdf) I found mentions an unresolved conjecture of Mossinghoff and Trudgian that $L_{1/2}(x) \leq 0$ for all $x \geq 17$. This would settle the question, and apparently it's been verified that $L_{1/2}(x) \leq 0$ for $17 \leq x \leq 10^{12}$. But it would be great to find a simpler resolution that doesn't depend on solving Riemann Hypothesis-adjacent questions. Any thoughts are much appreciated.

Comment: As someone who has worked on the $\alpha = 1/2$-conjecture of Mossinghoff and Trudgian, I would point out that this problem is *harder* than the Riemann hypothesis.

Comment: Thanks @Peter - I don't have much number theory background, so I really appreciate your input. This may be hard to answer, but does the problem of zeroes of these $P_n$ strike you as something that's likely to be capital-H Hard as well? I came to this from a different, relatively idle problem, and I'm just trying to decide whether to spend more time playing around with pretty elementary methods - or if I should recognize that I'm in deep waters.

Comment: It's hard for me to tell. The usual techniques from analytic number theory don't seem to get you anywhere nontrivial. I wouldn't expect it to be easy.

Comment: Roger that - thanks again.